# Android Extract Audio from Video

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio, video

I am using this libraey https://gist.github.com/ArsalRaza/132a6e99d59aa80b9861ae368bc786d0 to extract audio from my video. I saw a lot of recommendations to use it. But for some reason I am getting a **null pointer exception** on the following.

```
// Set up the orientation and starting time for extractor.
    MediaMetadataRetriever retrieverSrc = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retrieverSrc.setDataSource(srcPath);
```

But when I debug **retrieverSrc** is not being null (this is obvious because I am already creating a new instance).

**srcPath** is https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1499813059644305416/pu/vid/902x720/-b3JbGZm825Q6PwT.mp4

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so instead of what I was using I used this

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retrieverSrc = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retrieverSrc.setDataSource(srcPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
```

**notice how I added a HashMap in the second parameter**